# Reinstalling Ubuntu via clean install on a machine I can't physically access

Tags: system-installation, ssh

I'm in a bit of an interesting predicament. I have a computer running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 32-bit that I currently can only access remotely (via ssh). I need to install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu on this computer. How could I go about doing a clean install of Ubuntu remotely? I'm not particularly attached to any data or configuration stored on the computer because I have backups, so I don't mind if it involves wiping the hard drive.

Comment: Might be useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/291371/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-via-ssh

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OverSSH

Comment: @M.Becerra I saw the first one, but I wasn't sure if the process would be different 6 years later. The second link is very helpful - if you make an answer out of it, I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Im not sure how useful and safe would be to post it as an answer, it's a rather dangerous thing to do and the guide is pretty old too.